# Is there a class in java 8 that implements a "null-terminated" stream without having to roll my own?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Or is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?  I'd like to create a stream based on a Supplier (which are normally infinite), but have the stream terminate when the supplier returns null.  I made this myself, but it seems like a fair amount of work to accomplish a pretty simple concept.

```
public class NullTerminatedStreamFactory {

    static int characteristics = Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.DISTINCT;

    public static<T> Stream<T> makeNullTerminatedStream(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new NullTerminatedSpliteratorFromSupplier<>(supplier, Long.MAX_VALUE, characteristics), false);
    }

    static class NullTerminatedSpliteratorFromSupplier<T> extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> {

        public NullTerminatedSpliteratorFromSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier, long est, int additionalCharacteristics) {
            super(est, additionalCharacteristics);
            this.supplier = supplier;
        }

        public Supplier<T> supplier;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            T next = supplier.get();
            if (next != null) {
                action.accept(next);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, I'm using it like this, to basically create a Stream from a BlockingQueue:

```
NullTerminatedStreamFactory.makeNullTerminatedStream(() -> {
            try {
                BlockingQueue<Message> queue = getBlockingQueue();
                return queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception while trying to get message from queue", e);
            }
            return null;
        });
```

Comment: You can probably use [`Stream::takeWhile`](http://download.java.net/jigsaw/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)... once Java 9 is released...

Comment: As of Java 8, I don’t think that there will be an alternative. You may improve your solution by providing a straight-forward `forEachRemaining` implementation, and you obviously may report `NONNULL` characteristic though I don’t think that it makes a difference in the current implementation.

Comment: @assylias Great, thanks for the heads up.  Seems like it would be as easy as `Stream.generate(...supplier...).takeWhile(o -> o != null)`

Comment: @Holger NONNULL definitely makes sense.  Is there any reason to provide a forEachRemaining implementation?  I don't quite see what could be gained by changing the `do { } while (tryAdvance(action)); }` default implementation, for the generic case at least.

Comment: @Paul Whalen: that’s hard to predict. In the best case, Hotspot will optimize the default `forEachRemaining` to a degree that it makes no difference. In the other cases, the nested operation requires more stack space and doubles the number of conditional operations. In most cases, I would tell you not to waste time on such optimizations, but in this case the specialized `forEachRemaining` implementation is so simple and straight-forward, that it doesn’t hurt, and, well, it’s the back-end for almost all non-short-circuiting stream operations…

Comment: Of course, I’m talking about something like `for(;;) { T next = supplier.get(); if(next==null) break; action.accept(next); }` that doesn’t invoke `tryAdvance`. It’s not a big deal and won’t hurt, if it doesn’t improve performance on a particular JVM.

Comment: @Holger: That should be an answer on its own. People forget that they can always work around FP limitations by falling back to trivial imperative approaches...

Comment: I really didn't get the use case here.  BlockingQueue -> Supplier -> Stream ??  Is this just to build a lambda?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe - The idea is to have a semantics of a stream, but the block-until-present property of a blocking queue.  If I created a stream directly from the blocking queue, the stream would only process as many elements as the queue has when a terminal operation on the stream is called (as evidenced by the LBQSpliterator implementation in LinkedBlockingQueue).  This would be undesirable in the example I created, where i would prefer to wait a second before deciding that no more elements will be placed in the blocking queue, ending the processing of the stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already found a perfectly valid hand-made implementation.

As mentioned in the comments, Java 9 seems to add a [`takeWhile(Predicate)`](http://download.java.net/jigsaw/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) method. Until then, you could use a third-party library that implements something like `takeWhile()`:

#### jOOλ

[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) has `limitWhile()`, which does the same thing:

```
Seq.generate(supplier).limitWhile(Objects::nonNull);
```

(disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOλ)

#### Javaslang

[Javaslang](http://javaslang.com) implemented their own `Stream` class, which is inspired by the Scala collections, and thus has `takeWhile()`

```
Stream.gen(supplier).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
```

#### Functional Java

[Functional Java](http://www.functionaljava.org/) also ship with their own `Stream` implementation, that has a `takeWhile()` method:

```
Stream.fromFunction(i -> supplier.get()).takeWhile(o -> o != null);
```